# Laravel AuthServiceProvider code explanation

Tags: laravel-5.1

I'm starting to user Gate in Laravel 5.1, and I got this code from some where in the internet.

```
<?php    

public function boot(GateContract $gate)
{
    $this->registerPolicies($gate);

    /**
     * NOTE!!
     * First time migration will fails, because permissions table doesn't exists.
     */
    foreach($this->getPermissions() as $permission) {
        $gate->define($permission->path, function($user) use ($permission) {

            return $user->hasRole($permission->roles);
        });
    }
}
```

My question is, what is `function($user) use ($permission) {` in `$gate->define($permission->path, function($user) use ($permission) {` ??? Why is there `use` after `function()`?

If there're some references, I'd love to know/ read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been described in document of PHP.
Please refer to the example 3 of http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php.

> Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such variables must be passed to the use language construct.

Your case is

```
    $user->hasRole($permission->roles)
```

is necessary in order to use the variable of $permission.

Comment: haaa.. thanks so much. It's always so hard to find out what it is, if I dont know the keyword/ the terms..